# 'TProtocol' does not contain a definition for 'IncrementRecursionDepth'

Tags: c#, thrift, thrift-protocol

I've installed thrift for both my library and server; using **NuGet**.

I have a very simple thrift file that I've compiled it using the following command:

**`thrift.exe -r --gen csharp node.thrift`**

the node.thrift has three lines:

```
service Server {
    string ping()
}
```

I get the errors from the **Server.cs** generated by the **thrift** compiler.

**'TProtocol' does not contain a definition for 'IncrementRecursionDepth'**

sample line throwing the error:

```
public void Read (TProtocol iprot)
    {
      iprot.IncrementRecursionDepth(); //this line has the error
```

I've googled for it, but didn't find any results.

**update**: If I delete the lines throwing the error, the library compiles and the server works as expected, I don't know if I'll face errors in the future or not, whats up with the recursion?!

**important point**: I compile the thrift file using the executable I've downloaded from **`http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/thrift/0.9.3/thrift-0.9.3.exe`**. the version is **0.9.3** but the thrift library installed by NuGet is **0.9.1.3**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the version is 0.9.3 but the thrift library installed by NuGet is 0.9.1.3

Thats exactly the problem. The `IncrementRecursionDepth()` function has been added later to prevent a problem, which is outlined in more detail in [THRIFT-3235](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3235). Since you need both compiler and library for it, you get a problem.

**Solution:** Always use matching compiler and libraries. In particular, use 0.9.3.

Comment: I couldn't find NuGet packages for 0.9.3, is there a way I can make it my own (using a simple wizard)?

Comment: All [official packages are listed here](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/), plus some 3rdparty ones. [This is the 0.9.3 for C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ApacheThrift/0.9.3). If the Thrift compiler is missing from that package (I'm not sure, but IIRC there was some issue with the EXE missing), you can [get it here](https://thrift.apache.org/download).

Comment: I searched for the wrong package, please include this in your answer:

To install the latest official package from NuGet, search for ApacheThrift.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem was that the compiler version was not equal to the thrift version installed by NuGet.

To install the latest official package from NuGet, search for **ApacheThrift**.